# Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved for iis hosted wcf service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

any help is appricited
I have one Sample service and one Test console application 
I have accessing sample service metadata by adding reference from same soln to the console appln and i am getting binding info.
also i am hosting(publishing) same service in IIS and adding reference through service URL in Test Console appln and I am Getting result.

Now problem is tat my running Data service hosted(published) in IIS i am adding the reference and trying to read the metadata from service URL its giving me Error.
***Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:9092/TransactionDataService.svc/mex'***.

I am using mexhttpbinding with multiplebingind = true in both(sample + my running data service) cases

web config for samp-le serviec

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="ServiceApp.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="Service1Endpoint" contract="ServiceApp.IService1"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Code for accesing metadata

```
EndpointAddress serviceEndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:30617/Service1.svc/mex");

            var endpointCollection = MetadataResolver.Resolve(typeof(IService1), serviceEndpointAddress);


            foreach (var endpoint in endpointCollection)
            {
                Type bindingType = endpoint.Binding.GetType();

                if (bindingType.Equals(typeof(WSHttpBinding)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Eureka!!!");
                }
            }
```

web config for Data service

```
<bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttp" openTimeout="01:00:00" closeTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="0" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

    <!--Service Behaviors-->
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="DataAccessBehavior">
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

    <!--Service Configuration-->
        <services>
            <service name="TransactionDataAccess" behaviorConfiguration="DataAccessBehavior">
                <endpoint name="DataAccessServiceEndpoint" address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttp" contract="TransactionDataServices.ITransactionDataService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
```

Code for accesing metadata for data service is same except serviec url

Answer (score 2):

See if by any chance you forgot to decorate your transported classes with `[DataContract]` attributes (don't forget `[DataMember]` as well).